# Control file access per user?

Tags: chown

Embarrassed to ask this, but have never had to face this before, so... here goes.

Some things to know:

- I have terabytes of storage on a PC that is connected to my television.
- I have kids who think the word "DELETE" means "FUN!"

What I'd like to do is:

- Be able to leave the PC logged in.
- Lock down `/mnt/media1` and `/mnt/media2` from the PC's default user (chow)
- Any changes to the above done via `sudo`

Ideally, I'd mount those as read-only and then use the `sudo` command on all `cp`, `mv`, etc. changes I'd need...

`chown`, `mount`?

Help. :)  Before my kids delete 400 gigabytes of the photos we've taken of them. :P

-Chow

Comment: The recommended way for access control is setting up **acl**. See the following questions for solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82628/how-to-make-a-directory-with-permanent-permissions-different-from-default, http://askubuntu.com/questions/46716/how-to-restrict-users-on-deleting-files, http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to simply change the ownership and permissions of all the files. Beware that this may take a while, depending on how much you have saved on your drives. You can leave it mounted read-write, but you would still need to use `sudo` for all operations to the files.

Assuming they are already mounted (at the locations stated above), you can just do:

```
chmod -R o-w,a+r /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2
chown -R root:root /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2
```

The first command makes all the files within `/mnt/media1` and `/mnt/media2` readable to everybody and writable only to the owner or group. The next command changes the owning user and group to root so that you need to use `sudo` to modify anything on the drive. You will only have to run these commands once; after that, they are permanently stored on the drive.

This will sufficiently protect your drive from user tampering while maintaining the readability of its stored contents.

Comment: Those commands aren't changing the mod/ownership of the files.  I forgot to mention, the drive is ntfs... would that prevent me from achieving this?

Comment: @chow that is a problem, as Unix-style permissions are not supported in NTFS. I will add another answer to try to solve this problem.

Comment: Ended up reformatting the drives as `ext4` and this works like a charm.  Needed to `sudo chown -r root:root /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2` though to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the drive is formatted as NTFS, something different than normal needs to be done. As NTFS does not support Unix-style file permissions, you will need to protect your drive by mounting it read-only. Assuming it is already mounted, you can do:

```
sudo umount /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2
sudo mount -o ro /dev/<device> /mnt/media1
sudo mount -o ro /dev/<device> /mnt/media2
```

These will remount your drives in read-only mode, so you can't even modify them with `sudo`. To be able to modify them, do:

```
sudo umount /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2
sudo mount -o rw /dev/<device> /mnt/media1
sudo mount -o rw /dev/<device> /mnt/media2
```

Make your modifications (without sudo), and then execute the top two commands to protect them again.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: `[chow] (/mnt)
>> sudo mount -o remount,rw /mnt/media1
Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and then mount it once again.`

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
chmod -R o-w,a+r /mnt/media1 /mnt/media2
```

is sufficient.

and open standard accounts for kids.

change your password with `passwd` command.

That would be easier than typing `sudo` for any change to the disks.