# Permissions issue

Tags: permissions, chmod

Which would be the right `chmod` value for a directory where everyone can write on it, but only the owner of the content can delete it?

I thought `chmod 1755 path_to_directory` would be the right one, but it isn't.

I am beginner on linux, i tried finding this on google, but i wasn't successful.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Probably not. This question is really about making users *own* files they create in a particular directory (see the answer here; unlike [that situation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46716/how-to-restrict-users-on-deleting-files), ACLs are not needed here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to allow everyone to write to the directory, but restrict deletions to only the owner of the content.
So, the right command would be:

```
chmod 1777 path_to_directory
```

The "others" must have write permission to create things (and the "sticky bit" restricts deletions).
Read the man page of `chmod` to understand it better (`man chmod`).

An equivalent (and probably easier to understand) command is:

```
chmod a+rwx,+t path_to_directory
```

- `a+rwx` adds read (r), write (w) and execute (x) permission to all (a)
- `+t` adds the "sticky bit" to the directory (which restricts deletion of files/folders inside to just their owner)

Comment: This seems the solution to my problem. I will test it.